# Can't recover docker swarm from pending state

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, containers, docker-swarm

There was a crash and I have this issue now where it says docker swarm status is pending and the node status is UNKNOWN. This is my `docker info` result

```
swarm@swarm-manager-1:~$ docker info
Containers: 270
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 270
Images: 160
Server Version: 1.12.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 1211
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: host bridge null overlay
Swarm: pending
 NodeID: d9hq8wzz6skh9pzrxzhbckm97
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: 5zgab5w50qgvvep35eqcbote2
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 2
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: HIDDEN
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-91-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 6.804 GiB
Name: swarm-manager-1
ID: AXPO:VFSV:TDT3:6X7Y:QNAO:OZJN:U23R:V5S2:FU33:WUNI:CRPK:2E2C
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

This is my docker node ls result:

```
ID                           HOSTNAME         STATUS   AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
9tlo3rg7tuc23xzc3am28lak1    swarm-worker-1   Unknown  Active        
d9hq8wzz6skh9pzrxzhbckm97 *  swarm-manager-1  Unknown  Active        Leader
```

I've tried restarting docker engine and the VM but doesn't help in any way. The system is actually running as when I say `docker ps` in the worker it shows all the containers but on the manager there is nothing on `docker ps`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Swarm the only solution to similar trouble was to destroy the swarm. And when you do this you should probably also do a `docker system prune` (only if theres nothing valuable that could be deleted) and `service docker restart`. And then set up a new swarm.

It sucks. I know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just rebuilding the whole swarm all at once, you can attempt to remove and re-add each node one at a time - the advantage of this is that the swarm state is not destroyed and, on larger swarms, services can continue while you fix it.  This process is considerably more complicated when you don't have a quorum of managers, though.

First, note the node IDs (I'll refer to here as $WORKER_ID and $MANAGER_ID).

On manager node:

```
docker node update --availability drain $WORKER_ID
```

^ This is optional, but it's a good habit when working with live services on a swarm.

```
docker swarm join-token manager
```

^ This command will give you the join command to run on each node after it's removed. I'll refer to it as $JOIN_COMMAND below. We will demote the worker once the manager re-joins.

On worker:

```
docker swarm leave
$JOIN_COMMAND
```

This node is now re-joined as a manager, but I'll continue calling it the 'worker' to avoid confusion.

On manager:

```
docker node rm $WORKER_ID
docker node update --availability drain $MANAGER_ID
docker swarm leave -f
$JOIN_COMMAND
docker node rm $MANAGER_ID
docker node ls
```

Find the worker's new id (pay attention to the hostname, not the role) -> $NEW_WORKER_ID

```
docker node demote $NEW_WORKER_ID
```

Your swarm should be refreshed - if there were more nodes, the services running on each would have migrated across the swarm when you drained each node.

If it still doesn't work (and regardless), you *really* should consider upgrading to docker v17.06 or newer.  Swarm networking was very unstable before that, causing a lot of issues stemming from race conditions.